More elements with the same id, how to scrape
I'm scraping for an uni project and I wanted to scrape the genres of tvshows from IMbd. In the image you can find the html. I used the following code:
url1 = 'https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/?ref_=chttvtp_t_1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response1 = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.content, 'html.parser')

genres= soup1.find("a", class_="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link").text
print(genres)


but it scrapes the "Creation", that is at the beginning of the site and has the same class name, and not the genres.
I tried using soup.find_all so I could scrape all the ele,emts with that specific class but it gives me the error "ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"
Where is the problem?
I also wanted to applicate that function to all the urls I scraped, but I'm not very good with for loops. How can i create a for loop to applicate that function to this data frame:
tvshows_url= pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            'link':f'https://www.imdb.com{link.get("href")}',
            'title': link.text.split('. ')[-1]
        }
        for link in soup.select('a[href^="/title"]:has(h3)')
    ]
)
print(tvshows_url)



You have to select your elements more specific, always take in view its parents or siblings. I used css selectors in this case and get_text() with parameters to join/split the texts:
genres= soup1.select_one('[data-testid="genres"]').get_text('|', strip=True)
print(genres)

Leads to :
Crime|Drama|Thriller


However you can make it a bit easier while focus the some script data and load it directly into dataframe:
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'}).content,
    "html.parser"
)

data = []

for link in soup.select('a[href^="/title"]:has(h3)')[:3]:
    # (I limited the results by slicing to three for demo purpose here simply remove the slice [:3] from the for-loop to get all)
    data.append(
        json.loads(
            BeautifulSoup(
                requests.get(f'https://www.imdb.com{link.get("href")}',headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'}).content,
                "html.parser"
            ).find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}).text
        )
    )

pd.json_normalize(data)


Oh thank you, now it works. So if I have understand well, the for loop you created scrapes all the text infos and url? Now if I want to access them singulary and save them, how can I do it?

How can I do the same as you did for the genres for the stars? Because they have the same id as the "creation", so I receive in output the creation and I can't find a different identificator. Thank you

Stars is almost the same, check the unique identifiers, HTML elements, ... and select them: soup1.select_one('li:has([href*="fullcredits/cast"]) ul').get_text('|', strip=True) but I would not do it the complecated way. Use the dataframe created from the JSON string and pick you information or transform / save it to what ever you need .to_csv(), .to_json(),....

I tried to use he dataframe created from the JSON string and I managed to pick the informations I need but for actors and creator I have all the informations '[{'@type': 'Person', 'url': 'https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0186505/', 'name': 'Bryan Cranston'}....' and I can't pick just the name. I tried normalizing it with jonson but it divides it for the actors and not for 'type', 'url' and 'name' . I have the same problem for creator

Please keep in mind, also for future questions, that in many cases only food for thought and not a 100% solution can be shown if the question does not outline a corresponding goal.  However if you have your dataframe simply convert the dicts into a string of names - This gets you a new column with the result df['actors_names'] = ['|'.join([a.get('name') for a in l]) for l in df['actor']] - For additional questions try asking a new question with exact its focus - This keeps the posts cleaner. Thanks
